# requirejs optimizer error: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to use requirejs optimizer, but I get the following error:

running from node:

```
$ node r.js js/main.js -o build.js
Error: Evaluating js/app/main.js as module "app/main" failed with error: 
Error: Evaluating js/lib/jquery-1.8.0.js as module "jquery" failed 
with error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

running from java

```
$ java -classpath js/lib/dist/js.jar:js/lib/dist/compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r.js js/main.js
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.

js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.

js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.
```

I think somehow I should tell the compiler that the source is supossed to run from a web browser (just a guess)...

Comment: oops, just found this doc... http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html, I rushed a little bit to ask here...

Answer (score 0):

I had my config file set like this:

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone',
        backboneLocalStorage: 'lib/backbone.localStorage',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore',
        util: 'lib/util',
        config: 'config',
        lang: 'lang',
        hammer: 'lib/hammer',
        moment: 'lib/jquery_plugins/moment',
        slider: 'lib/jquery_plugins/slider'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jquery'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        hammer: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'Hammer'
        },
        slider: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        moment: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

And I had to change

```
jquery: {
            exports: 'jquery'
        },
```

to

```
jquery: ['jquery'],
```

which seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Just remove the jquery dependency in the component and it should solve it.

Something like 
`define(['jquery'],
function GoogleMapsLoader($) {`

should be replaced with

`define(function GoogleMapsLoader() {`

Reading [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Pancake/RequireJS_Build_Step) should help you.